# VBA run time error 91

Tags: vba

I have a problem with this code in VBA, getting run time error 91.

```
 Private ChkTemp(90) As Checkbox

 ChkTemp(0) = Temp1
 .
 .
 .
 ChkTemp(89) = Temp90
```

I tried to assign a design time `checkbox(Temp1)` to my newly declared `checkbox(ChkTemp)`.

Comment: Which flavour VBA? Excel, Word, Access ... ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to;

```
Private ChkTemp(90) As MSForms.CheckBox
```

And to assign the object reference you must use `set`;

```
Set ChkTemp(0) = Temp1
```

You can also;

```
Private ChkTemp(1 To 90) As MSForms.CheckBox
...
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(ChkTemp)
    Set ChkTemp(i) = Me.Controls("Temp" & i)
Next
```